# Equivalent of COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS in Teradata

Tags: teradata, collation

What is the equivalent of SQL Server notation - `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` in Teradata?

Example:

```
Create table emp(
company varchar(6) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teradata supports only two basic character set LATIN and UNICODE, in your case `company varchar(6) LATIN` probably matches.

Sorting rules can be changed on session level (most end users don't know about this and simply use the default assigned to them by the DBA).

Case-insensitiv comparison is the default for Teradata-mode sessions (most systems run in this mode).